# No module named 'sportsreference'

Tags: python, pip

I pip installed the `sportsreference` package in my command prompt and it shows successful. Yet when I try to call it in my Jupyter Notebook it says no module named `sportsreference`.

Any help on what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interpreter that your Jupyter uses to run the cells is not the one you installed that package into. Remember you can have not only different versions of Python interpreter, but also different virtual environments associated with each Python interpreter in your machine.

So either install the package in the interpreter that Jupyter uses, or run the Jupyter from the interpreter you've installed that package into.

The simplest solution is to install it in a Jupyter cell with:

```py
!pip install <your_package_name>
```

the `!` allows you to execute command.

To check which interpreter currently runs your code you can check the output of:

```py
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```